# Avoiding to change references to COM addins

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, excel-addins

I've used **COM addins** for some years and I've observed that often **new versions** were the cause of serious issues including crashes at **Excel** startup or when **COM components** are used.

From what I understand this is due to the internal Excel plumbing caching some information about the COM addin (inside the XLS/XLSX/XLA/XLAM file) that don't match its new versions: e.g. if a new method has been added to the API, or a new parameter has been added to a method.

This is really annoying as it forces us to remove the references in the **VBA editor** *"Tools" -> "References"* menu, close the popup, and add them back, which AFAIK forces Excel to resync with the current state of the addin.

A "simple" fix would be to add a hook on *Workbook_Open*, for each distributed workbook, to automatically remove, if it exists, then add each reference back.

Do you have any other/better idea ?

Comment: Hmya, it is supposed to fail.  Running an add-in with the old version of the type library and a new version of the code doesn't make sense and cannot work.  If it is "annoying" then just write a SOP so it isn't your job to update the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HansPassant. The TLB is deployed/registered with the new DLL so I don't get how this could be an issue. What do you mean by a "SOP"?